# Why are most supercomputer using linux?

Tags: linux, hpc

Referring to this [BBC Article: Supercomputing superpowers](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/10187248.stm)

Almost all the supercomputers are using Linux as operating system. Why is Linux so popular?

Comment: I think this is a valid/real question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Operating_systems_used_on_top_500_supercomputers.svg

Answer (score 4):

Scalability, for one. Also, the fact that it is open source is important, since super computers exist almost solely for research and researchers love the flexibility of open-source software. They can hack and slash the OS to be ultra-tuned to fit their very specific need at the small cost of the source code and some bandwidth for anyone that's curious about what they did.

Comment: +1, the ability to "hack and slash the OS" is 99% of it. The cost is most of the other 1%.

Comment: I think cost plays a much bigger factor.  It's no coincidence that most of the top players in the above link are free.  Hardware compatibility plays a big part too, and Linux has arguably the best.

Comment: @churnd - For someone spending millions on a supercomputer, AIX or Windows licenses are not an issue.

Comment: @churnd, Windows HPC server is about $100/server for a larger cluster. That's a very minor cost compared to the hardware and custom software.

Comment: @churnd, @Chris S, http://www.microsoft.com/hpc/en/us/how-to-buy/volume-licensing.aspx list it at $475/node. Cray XT5 (Jaguar) has ~25,000 computing nodes. Assuming your price ($100/node) this would bring the OS licence to 2.5M USD. Please do correct me if I am wrong in calculating the license.